# Unit testing ES7 React components with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, babeljs, jestjs

How do you make Jest play nicely with ES7 initializers? I've searched far a wide on here and other sources, but didn't find anything conclusive.

`.babelrc.js`

```
{
    "env": {
        "development": {
            "presets": [["es2015", { "modules": false }], "react", "react-hmre"],
            "plugins": [
                "transform-class-properties",
                "react-hot-loader/babel"
            ]
        },
        "test": {
            "presets": ["env", "react"],
            "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
        },
        "production": {
            "presets": [["es2015", { "modules": false }], "react"],
            "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
        }
    }
}
```

`package.json`

```
    {
    "name": "demo",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "license": "MIT",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^15.5.4",
        "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-jest": "^20.0.3",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.2",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
        "enzyme": "^2.8.2",
        "react-hot-loader": "next",
        "babel-plugin-import": "^1.2.1",
        "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
        "enzyme-to-json": "^1.5.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "export NODE_ENV=test && ./node_modules/.bin/jest --no-cache"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">= 7.8.0"
    },
    "jest": {
        "verbose": true,
        "collectCoverage": true,
        "coverageDirectory": "__coverage__",
        "mapCoverage": true,
        "setupFiles": [
            "./tests/setup.js"
        ],
        "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
            "/node_modules/"
        ],
        "transform": {
            "\\.js$": "../node_modules/babel-jest"
        },
        "testRegex": ".*\\.test\\.js$",
        "snapshotSerializers": [
            "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
        ]
    }
}
```

`Demo.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export class Demo extends React.Component {

    static props = { name: PropTypes.string.isRequired };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='demo'>{this.props.name}</div>
        );
    }

}
```

`Demo.test.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Demo } from '..';
import { render } from 'enzyme';


describe('Demo', () => {
    it('renders correctly', () => {
        const wrapper = render(<Demo name="foo" />);
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

After running `yarn test` or `export NODE_ENV=test && ../node_modules/.bin/jest --no-cache`, Jest will complain that it sees an unexpected character

```
 8 |     props = {
   |           ^
 9 |         name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
```

From my understanding, the environment variable set when we run the tests should automatically transform the initializers to something which can be used by Jest, but this doesn't appear to be happening.

I am also using webpack 2.x, but the configuration overhead to get that to work seems daunting. Is there another way?

### Update 1

I modified my Jest settings as follows:

```
 "transform": {
      "\\.js$": "./node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"
 }
```

This failed immediately with:

> TypeError: Jest: a transform must export a `process` function.

Removing `transform` altogether yields a slightly different issue:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null

I also added the `constructor` to the `Demo` component.

Comment: It's a dumb question, but are you sure about the syntax for the new feature?  I've seen similar TC39 plugins out in the wild, but with `props: {name: ...}` instead of `props = {name: ...}`

Comment: Also, does the component render correctly, or does it only fail during Jest testing?

Comment: Works fine with webpack 2

Comment: Any progress on this issue? I also want to use class properties but no Jest support becomes a blocker. `create-react-app` nicely supports Jest testing with Babel class properties: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#supported-language-features-and-polyfills

Answer (score 3):

I believe if you are trying to add `propTypes`, with ES7 initializers and using the [`transform-class-properties`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) you need to do

```
static propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

So it would be

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export class Demo extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='demo'>{this.props.name}</div>
        );
    }

}
```

Pretty sure you do not have to explicitly define `props` as it is part of the `React.Component` when you extends from it. That or you may need to declare `constructor` and then call `super(props);`

Comment: Can you also confirm you have your `jest` set up correctly? You shouldn't need to use `babel-jest` anymore explicitly as it [ships with `jest` now](https://github.com/facebook/jest#using-babel). I'm not sure if your jest is actually transpiling the ES7 code correctly. It's possible you may need to specify to do `transform-class-properties` in `jest` although it shouldn't be necessary since you have a `.babelrc`

Comment: Hmm the error regarding process sounds webpack related. I would suggest taking a look at [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/334#issuecomment-220707702)? it looks like it should support webpack now but I see some people having to write a specific configuration in their webpack

Answer (score 1):

Jest uses babel to transpile JS code. You need to add support for ES7 features in .babelrc file.

Here are the steps:

1. Do `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0 babel-jest`
2. In your package.json, add `babel-jest` for transforming all the js files.
3. In your .babelrc file, add `"stage-0"` preset.

Here is how my **package.json** looks like:

```
...
"jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    }
}
...
```

And here is how my **.babelrc** file looks like:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ]
}
```